# The Swift Programming Language - Generics - issue with Where clauses

Tags: swift, generics, swift3, where-clause

In `The Swift Programming Language` book, available on the `iBooks Store`, in the `Generics` chapter, somewhere towards the end, it talks about **Generic Where Clauses** after having talked about `constraints`and `type constraints`. 
The following protocol is given:

```
protocol Container {
    associated type Item: Equatable
    mutating func append(_ item: Item)
    var count: Int { get }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Item { get }
}
```

The following function is then declared:

```
func allItemsMatch<C1: Container, C2: Container>(_ someContainer: C1, _ anotherContainer: C2) -> Bool where C1.Item == C2.Item, C1.Item: Equatable {
    // Check that both containers contain the same number of items.
    if someContainer.count != anotherContainer.count {
        return false
    }

    // Check each pair of items to see if they're equivalent.
    for i in 0..<someContainer.count {
        if someContainer[i] != anotherContainer[i] {
            return false
        }
    }

    // All items match, so return true.
    return true
}
```

To demonstrate this in action, the following struct had previously been declared:

```
struct Stack<Element>: Container {
    // original Stack<Element> implementation
    var items = [Element]()
    mutating func push(_ item: Element) {
        items.append(item)
    }
    mutating func pop() -> Element {
        return items.removeLast()
    }
    // conformance to the Container protocol
    mutating func append(_ item: Element) {
        self.push(item)
    }
    var count: Int {
        return items.count
    }
    subscript(i: Int) -> Element {
        return items[i]
    }
}
```

And now we come to the issue I am getting in Xcode (v9.0, macOS 10.12.6 FYI):

```
var stackOfStrings = Stack<String>()
stackOfStrings.push("uno")
stackOfStrings.push("dos")
stackOfStrings.push("tres")

var arrayOfStrings = ["uno", "dos", "tres"]

if allItemsMatch(stackOfStrings, arrayOfStrings) {
    print("All items match.")
} else {
    print("Not all items match.")
}
```

I am getting the following error next to the first line of the last `if-else`statement:

`Cannot invoke 'allItemsMatch' with an argument list of type '(Stack2<String>, [String])'`

As I have been learning to code for just three months now (and from scratch), I have no idea why this should fail, seeing that I am following the book to the letter.
Could someone explain why this is throwing an error and propose a possible solution?

Comment: You did not "follow the book to the letter": You added a constraint at `associated type Item: Equatable`, and you forgot to declare protocol adoption: `extension Array: Container { }` – Also there are some compiler errors with your code.

Comment: I am following the `Swift 4` edition of the book. Are you looking at my same version? Because that constraint you say I added is absolutely here in front of my eyes in the book. Also, the `extension` you talk about is not there in the book, please check if you don't believe me.

Comment: I am referring to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html – it's all in there.

Comment: I am sorry but I opened your link and there is no `extensionArray: Container { }`... also, adding that to my code is not solving the issue. I still get the error stated in the question

Comment: @NeeratheWildMage See my comment under my answer regarding the typos in your code above.

Comment: There *is* `extension Array: Container {}`.  – And there are actually 
*two* `protocol Container` examples. The one with `associatedtype Item: Equatable` is only an example in that paragraph, and not used in the subsequent code.

Comment: That was actually the issue ... possibly this book doesn't expect somebody who has never studied anything of coding before to start with this! :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. You copied the protocol definition incorrectly, it should be:

```swift
protocol Container {
  associatedtype Item
  mutating func append(_ item: Item)
  var count: Int { get }
  subscript(i: Int) -> Item { get }
}
```

[image: part 1]

2. You forgot to add the important line that conforms `Array` to `Container`:

```swift
extension Array: Container {}
```

[image: part 2]

Comment: Thanks for your help. As I am learning, I don't expect the book to leave out details like this one of adding the array conformity. The function doesn't work if the `Equatable`part is not written there.

Comment: @NeeratheWildMage I can confirm it works -- note that you have multiple typos in your `Stack` implementation. The functions' parameter lists should be `(_ item: Element)` not `(_item: Element)`. 

The `_` is Swift syntax for skipping an external parameter name, letting you call the function like this: `append(item)` rather than `append(item: item)`

Comment: I'm sorry ... the typos were only in this post, not in my code on the Mac

Comment: Ok, now it works. Thanks. I had added the line on extensions but not in the proper part. To study this I'm creating a playground and the book is re-declaring several things multiple times, which of course throws an error. I then change names and make a mess. Now I've gone back, /* commented */ the previous versions of the code which were not needed and it now works. Thank you all